# What kind of options use a root symbol that starts with a digit and ends with a stock ticker?

Tags: options

The OCC publishes memos about how corporate actions cause listed options to be adjusted.  Sometimes these memos specify option root symbols like '2DXC' alongside 'DXC' ([link to an OCC memo dated 3/31/17](https://www.theocc.com/webapps/infomemos;OCCPROD0PUBSESSION=C91322FF2F741DE864BB03DE74831E04.occ-ppube4l?number=40932&date=201703&lastModifiedDate=03%2F31%2F2017%2016%3A32%3A47)).

When are symbols like '2DXC' used?  What kind of options are these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These symbols are used for Flex options series

You can have a description of Flex options in either of the links below

http://www.cboe.com/products/flex-cflex

https://www.investopedia.com/terms/f/flexoption.asp